# How can I import typescript files in Vue3 SFC and build it using laravel mix

Tags: typescript, vue.js, laravel-mix

Suppose a vue3 SFC `Example.vue` that uses a function called `add` which is imported from a ts file called `useAdd.ts`

```
// Example.vue

<template/>
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

import useAdd from '../composables/useAdd.ts';

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const { add } = useAdd();

    return { add };
  },
});
</script>
```

```
// useAdd.ts

export default function useAdd() {
  const add = (x: number, y: number) => x + y;

  return { add };
}
```

How can I configure `laravel-mix` to succesfully build the vue component